# How to override css grouped styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a way to override a bootstrap accordian style.

```
.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse .panel-body {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

I am using an accordian inside a `<div class="settings"><div>`.  I can therefore overide certain styles with the settings selector.

```
.settings .panel-heading {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

But when I use the settings selector with the grouped styles at the top it doesn't work...

```
.settings.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse .panel-body {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

This also doesn't work...

```
.settings.panel-group .settings.panel-heading+.settings.panel-collapse .settings.panel-

body {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
```

Please can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: use "!important" with your style

Comment: Can you give me some more detail please - I've tried this and no joy I'm afraid...

Comment: If your accordian is inside `<div class="settings"><div>` shouldn't you add a space after `.settings` class in your CSS code ? The way you actualy use it, your DIV should be `<div class="settings panel-group"><div>` ...

Comment: You can use like this(border-top: 1px solid #ddd !important;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your markup looks like this:

```
<div class="settings">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you need to have a space in your css selector between the .settings and .panel-group to indicate a descendant element.

```
.settings .panel-group ... { }
```

If you have .settings.panel-group without a space, it means the markup would have to be `<div class="settings panel-group">`.

Comment: Thanks - I got it working using spaces and ","  - i.e. .settings .panel-group, .settings .panel-heading+ .settings.panel-collapse, .settings .panel-body {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    }  The space AND the comma were key.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  You do understand that the comma means to apply the rules to multiple selectors, right?  Just FYI, since your question doesn't make any reference to that.

Comment: I was trying to get the first style defintion to work within the settings div.  Unfortunately I failed to mention that I'd already tried, without success, to use spaces.  I then found that I needed commas to override the existing style.  I do a lot of development on various technologies but have not invested any real time in learning CSS (hence the use of Bootstrap :-) ).  I could do with finding a good "Learn CSS" resource I guess...

Comment: This one is kind of a cool way to learn about using selectors: http://benhowdle.im/cssselectors/.  Click on the items in the list and it gives you an example, shows you which elements it applies to and describes what the selector does.  I don't know about you, but visuals always help solidify things in my brain.